# SSH session of Termius keeps disconnecting

Tags: macos, ssh, timeout, termius

I am new to MAC. I am currently using MAC Book Air. I am familiar with mobaxterm where i can enable keep Alive to prevent SSH session from disconnecting. Since it is not supported  in MAC, some how I am able to find Termius something similar to Mobaxterm but the session keeps diaconnecting after some time. It would be great if someone help me to resolve the issue to keep Alive the SSH Sessions.

Thanks
Muneesh

Answer (score 3):

You can set your own keepalive setting in Termius. For example, in Termius for macOS, go to menu: *Preferences -> Terminal*, and find the *Keepalive Interval* section.

Comment: yep..i already keep it 60 sec..is there any recommended sttings there?